# Algorithm to find all pairs that satisfy equal sum properties

Tags: java, algorithm, sum

Recently I faced the following programming puzzle:
Given N, Write a program that can print all those pairs (X,Y) such that sum of 1.....X-1 is equal to sum of X+1......Y.
I tried to solve the program in following manner:

1. First compute prefix sum of all value of Y (1<=Y<=N) and stored in the set.
2. Iterate from 1 to N and determine all X such that X^2 is available in the above set.

Code:

```
// compute prefix sum
Set<Long> prefixSums = new HashSet<Long>();
for(long y=1; y<=N; y++){
   prefixSums.add(y*(y+1)/2);
}

// find all pairs .. (1,1) will always be a valid pair. 
int pairs = 1; 
for(long x=1;x<=N;x++){
   if(prefixSums.get(x*x)!= null){
    pairs++;
   }
}
```

E.g. Given N = 10. Valid (X,Y) pairs are (1,1) and (6,8)

It was giving the correct solution in linear time. But I ended up with Time error. I think the question was expecting a better running time (logn or constant).

Could you please tell how could the solution be improved in terms of time constraints.

Comment: What is the constraint on `N`? Can you add a rough implementation of what you've tried?

Comment: Range of N is defined by  Long (Java) data type.

Comment: Do you know a sum of an arithmetic progression?

Comment: @user58697 Please see the code.

Comment: OK. I posted the comment before the edit. Now the problem nails down to when `y*(y+1)/2` is a perfect square. Big hint: `y` and `y+1` are coprime.

Comment: @kcsquared Thanks a lot. That surely helps. I think I should close this question.

Comment: @user58697 looks like a bad question. It requires me to know this formula (( (0.25) * (3.0+2.0*(2**0.5))**k ).floor) in order to solve in time better than linear.

Comment: Looks like you've ignored the hint. A coprimality means that one of the factors is a square, and another is twice a square. E.g. `y+1 = a^2` and `y = 2*b^2`, or vice versa. In the first case we arrive to `a^2 - 2b^2 = 1`, a classic [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation). In the second case it is a modified Pell's equation; pretty much the same. Please study it; math is an ultimate optimizer.

Comment: @user58697 thanks a lot. I will surely study it. I love the last line "math is an ultimate optimizer". Can you tell some good resources to study relevant maths for algorithms or computer science.